# How to pass taxonomy reference field data into a views reference contextual filter arguement with PHP code?

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, views

My content type has a taxonomy reference and a view reference field. I currently want to pass the Term ID as an argument into my referenced View via a Contextual filter Taxonomy Term. If someone can provide me with an example of how to write the PHP code in the contextual section of my view that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the help text puts it, you just need to `return` the value. Of course, your actual question might be to access the term id but you have not specified that.

For example, if you want to show the view as a block on a regular node page, and the node contains the tid, you would use code like this:

```
// Lets assume that this view will always be shown on a node page.
$node = arg(1);
$tid = $node->field_term_reference[0][LANGUAGE_NONE]['value'];
return $tid;
```

This code could be improved a lot but it gives the basic idea.

As a side note, if your scenario is as per above, then consider using Panels and pass in the term id using contextual arguments.

Side note 2: Your screenshot shows filter dialog for Term Name whereas your question asks for term ID. I have given the example for the latter. I hope it helps get you started.